# Allowing nil values in erb tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I am trying to allow this tag to be ignored if it is empty. It is meant to show an image using active storage, however, if that image has not been added yet to the record it throws an error.

```
<%= image_tag url_for(a.object.image), size: "400x400" %>
```

Is there any way I can adjust the syntax to accommodate this?

Have tried this:

```
<%= image_tag url_for(a.object.image).nil?, size: "400x400" %>
```

And this:

```
<%= if image_tag url_for(a.object.image).nil?, size: "400x400" %>

  <h1>Add images here</h1>

<% else %>

  <% image_tag url_for(a.object.image), size: "400x400" %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: What error are you getting when using this code? Please include some more code surround this (up until your `do` statement if you have it).

Comment: @DylanReile, this does not seem to work. Im getting this syntax error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' ppend=( a&.object&.image.nil?, size: "400x400" );@output_buf ^

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it with your second code block. Change the predicate of your conditional to check `a&.object&.image.nil?`. Additionally, I believe ERB does not support `<%=` with `if`. Move the equal sign to the line with `image_tag`.

```
<% if a&.object&.image.nil? %>
  <h1>Add images here</h1>
<% else %>
  <%= image_tag url_for(a.object.image), size: "400x400" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi, it still doesnt like this <%= if a&.object&.image.nil? %> throwing up a syntax error :/

Comment: @WernerAdewole I'm not certain, but try moving the `=` off the line with `if` and moving it to the line with `image_tag`. I've updated my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
if a.object.image.present?
  <% image_tag url_for(a.object.image), size: "400x400" %>
end
```

meaning if a.object has an image then show it, if not then just ignore it